# How to use Tandem Queueing Network Process?

Tags: stochastic-calculus, probability-or-statistics

*Mathematica* provides `QueueingNetworkProcess` and `QueueingProcess`. However, I can't seem to figure out how to create a tandem queuing process: whenever a customer arrives, he first needs to go to server 1, then to server 2, then to server 3.

any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### 1) Using [`QueueingNetworkProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QueueingNetworkProcess.html) to define such a queuing process

With the customer arrival rate `arrivalRate` and the service rates at each server being `serviceRate1`, `serviceRate2`, and `serviceRate3`, respectively, you can define this queuing process by

```
g = {arrivalRate, 0, 0}; 
m = {serviceRate1, serviceRate2, serviceRate3};
r = {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}};
c = {1, 1, 1};

queuingProcess = QueueingNetworkProcess[g, r, m, c];
```

If you then want to compute the probability of e.g. having one customer at each server you can use:

```
sDist = StationaryDistribution[queuingProcess];
PDF[sDist, {1, 1, 1}]
```

> [image: output]

To get the performance measures at all three nodes for some numerical values one can use:

```
Table[QueueProperties[{queuingProcess /. {arrivalRate -> 5., serviceRate1 -> 7., 
  serviceRate2 -> 6.5, serviceRate3 -> 8.3}, i}], {i, 3}]
```

> [image: QueueProperties]

If you want to perform calculations for several different rates, starting with a function like

```
queuingProcessF[arrivalRate_, {serviceRate1_, serviceRate2_, serviceRate3_}] := 
 QueueingNetworkProcess[{arrivalRate, 0, 0}, {{0, 1, 0}, {0, 0, 1}, {0, 0, 0}}, 
  {serviceRate1, serviceRate2, serviceRate3}, {1, 1, 1}]
```

might be more appropriate, though.

---

### 2) Using the product of the individual [`QueueingProcess`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/QueueingProcess.html)es

You can define the same queuing process by first defining each individual queue

```
q1 = QueueingProcess[arrivalRate, serviceRate1];
q2 = QueueingProcess[arrivalRate, serviceRate2];
q3 = QueueingProcess[arrivalRate, serviceRate3];
```

and then use [`ProductDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ProductDistribution.html?q=ProductDistribution) to generate the same [`StationaryDistribution`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StationaryDistribution.html?q=StationaryDistribution):

```
sDist2 = ProductDistribution[StationaryDistribution[q1], StationaryDistribution[q2], 
           StationaryDistribution[q3]];

PDF[sDist2, {1, 1, 1}] == PDF[sDist, {1, 1, 1}]
```

> ```
> True
> ```

Comment: Karsten, thank you so much! I see all the calculations are related to each queue in the network. What if I wanted to get the network performance? For example, how would I go about calculating the average number of customers in the network or the average network delay?

Comment: @user21522 The average number of customers in the network is `Total @ Table[QueueProperties[{queuingProcess, n}, "MeanSystemSize"], {n, 3}]`, isn't it. I can't see a way to get the network performance more directly in the moment.